# How should we be handling users who refuse to respond to criticism?

Tags: discussion, comments, criticism

I have noticed a common trend among *way* too many users here, where someone will post a post with obvious flaws (some more obvious than others), but fail to respond to any commentary either criticising the post or seeking clarifications (either by replying to the comment or by improving the post to address the issues).

Sometimes this is because the user is a first-time poster who just doesn't return to the site (or doesn't understand how the site is supposed to work), but I have also seen this behaviour among long-standing users who have been active for years.  In either case, this often results in problematic posts just…sitting there… being unfixed for indefinite periods of time.

Ideally, if abandoned by the original authors these posts could still be worked into shape by the community at large, but in my experience this is rarely if ever how things turn out: I am constantly seeing flawed posts days, months, even *years* old that are *still* untouched since the day they were posted, even *with* numerous critical comments posted.  Often by users who are *still* active.

How exactly should we be dealing with these situations?

Answer (score 1):

Not only those answers with critical comments posted below their answers, but also out dated answers like e.g. Answers about apostasy in Islam, which were totally biased onto justifying a false premise which today are out dated.

Maybe the community users who come across those type of posts and also who care for the welfare of the site, should edit the post to include ....

> **EDIT:** Warning: This post is either obsolete, or could not handle later criticism. We're doing our level best to take necessary actions on this. Hence, until then, the readers are requested to oblige to consider this information provided in this post at their own risk.

As stated, mean while....

if those posts are **too much stupid**, can be voted to **delete** by the high rep guys. (Maybe not the mods, cuz one vote is enough for them and they could be biased at any time)

If the posts are **obsolete** and there are posts which are new and contain latest and correct information, then those outdated answers are to be either deleted or notified properly and they should be closed **pointing the latest posts** or should include the link to new answers in their answers, or lock the post and then point to the new answer or **something appropriate**.

If the posts are **alright** to the most extent and are **problematic to a little** extent only, then a **new meta about that and probably a new question regarding that issue in the main site** should be opened. After perfect answers, either the old post should be updated, or pointed to the new one appropriately.

---

In case if the above posts are answers, and if there **are** answers on top of them if you feel these answers contain most of the info **redundant** which is already there in the answers top of them, then they can be **deleted** by the high rep guys.

Remember, in any case, if you're unsure of what you're doing with the post, follow the **simple and safest rule**, *take it to meta.*