# Encouraging downvoters to give constructive feedback

Tags: discussion, questions, etiquette

Can the moderators , *somehow*, encourage the act of providing feedback to a downvoted answer , *possibly in the comment section of the answer*, as this might guide people in the right direction, *especially newbies*.
P.s : I believe this might increase the engagement of new members significantly, as currently it seems most answers are provided by the same people .

Comment: [Users below 2000 rep are already encouraged to give constructive feedback](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes). Other than that, [the community has rejected *many* stricter feature requests to this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/135?sort=newest)

Comment: @AndrewT.   That was a very interesting read , seems that the stack exchange community has already debated this a hundred times over , plenty of arguments for and against , and now I learned to search the meta stack exchange before posting here . Thanks for that !

Comment: See also related post: https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1627/22